# For what value(s) of h is dim (Nul(A)) = 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

[Photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V8vn.png)

I'm not allowed to show images unless I get 10 reputation points so sorry for just providing a link. Could someone help me with this problem? Not sure how to do it, or what it's necessarily asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

By the *rank-nullity theorem*, you have to determine when $A$ has rank $2$ (it has necessarily rank $2$ or $3$).

First swap rows so the first two rows  do not depend on $h$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1 \\
5&-4&3h \\
1&3&h+5 \\
3&7&4
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1 \\ 
3&7&4 \\
5&-4&3h \\
1&3&h+5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then use *Gauß' pivot method*. You should obtain something like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1 \\ 
0&1&1\\
0&0& ?\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
from which you'll deduce the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty confused on this. Isn't rank(A) the dimensions of the column space? Col(A) = R^m = R^4 right? So rank(A) = 4?

Comment: It's the dimension (*without an s*) of the column space, which is a subspace of $\mathbf R^4$, and it's the same as the dimension of the row space, which is a subspace of $\mathbf R^3$.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Dimension* I don't quite understand your hint. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you know the pivot method?

Comment: Yes, but I've only done that for a square matrix when turning it into an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: You can do it for any matrix. It will end up into a triangular matrix with final zero rows. The number of non-zero rows is the rank. That's what my hint was about. Go ahead! You'll see it's not hard.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!